# Laravel Mix not recognising trailing comments eg "/*!".... Vue.js

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

$ npm run dev works fine

but $ npm run production, although its been working for months, now it does not recognise the "/*!" at the end of the compiled javascript lines to comment out the code eg

`/*!    <- this is the line not being recognised 
 * Vue.js v2.4.2
 * (c) 2014-2017 Evan You
 * Released under the MIT License.
 */`

This line is at the end of the compiled line. It can be fixed manually by returning it to a new line, but how can I get mix to automate it again?

Error =

`fallbackLoader option has been deprecated - replace with "fallback"
loader option has been deprecated - replace with "use"
 10% building modules 7/19 modules 12 active ...ode_modules/style-loader/addStyles.js(node:11800) DeprecationWarning: loaderUtils.parseQuery() received a non-string value which can be problematic, see https://github.com/webpack/loader-utils/issues/56`

Tried:
$ rm rf node_modules && npm clear cache && npm install

Using 
node v7.5.0
npm v4.1.2

package.json {

devDependencies
mix ^0.6.0,
"babel-core": "^6.23.1",
"babel-loader": "^6.3.2",
"bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7"

}

Comment: What is your Laravel Mix version?

Comment: "laravel-mix": "^0.6.0"

Comment: Update to v1.4.3 and see if problem still exist.

Answer (score 0):

Updated npm packages
Ultimately I think 'npm update vue' fixed it